# What happened to the AIM SDK?

Tags: c#, sdk, download, aim

I can no longer find a proper download for the AIM SDK. I've searched and searched everywhere but all I get are results for dev.aol.com and some guy's dead blog, neither of which provide the SDK. I can't even find anything saying it died, or was discontinued.

I last got the sdk from http://dev.aol.com/aim/sdk but now all I get is that I'm not logged in, despite the fact that I am, and have a developer key, and have a DevId registered to the same account.

I had it once way back when (2008-2009), when I had XP, but all the data on that drive is long-since gone.

If anyone could help me find a valid download somewhere, anywhere I'd be very happy. If not could you shed some light on what happened?

-Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are still looking for the link or not, but here it is if you need it i found it on Softpedia: http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/AOL-Instant-Messenger-SDK-Download-47207.html

Good Luck!

Comment: Download link is dead. I've been searching for the SDK to no avail. It really looks like third party apps that use the OSCAR protocol kept secret by aol do it by reverse engineering the protocol, as aol won't give it up or provide a SDK anymore.